# How to use tor for vpn in Linux

Tags: linux, vpn, linux-mint, tor

I live in Iran, and I wanted to filter the country most of the time. How to use Tor, which is not the terminal and the browser. I can not open my Facebook because of the filter.
And I'm writing to the terminal on Tor, like this way:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are a beginning Tor user and just need webbrowsing, it might be easier to go with the [Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en). It is an easy to use browser, which has a lot of optimizations designed to keep you as anonymous as possible.

Keep in mind that using software to circumvent the blockades put in by the government might be illegal in your country.

Comment: Yes, it's a crime in my country, but it does not work. How to use a browser for the terminal

Comment: Can you show what exactly is not working about Tor Browser? Your screenshot shows you only launched Tor, which is not enough, you also need a proxy to guide the traffic through Tor. That's why I recommended Tor Browser instead of the standard Tor distribution, makes things a lot easier.